# Automatically check new rows added to table and apply functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have new data being added to a postgres table. Either as the data comes in (or after it is added), I would like to check the data against other tables (and if all checks are ok) add the data to master tables.

To make it concrete, here's an example:

- A subscription request is made by a customer
- This request is automatically processed and information is added to a psql request_input table (via kafka streams and connectors)
- Either as its being added/after it is added, I would like to check that the subscriber does not exist already (in a separate subscriber table)
- If the subscriber does not exist, add their information to the subscriber table, payment details to the payments table, subscription preferences to the subscription preferences table etc.

What I would like is that, as each request comes in (and appended to the request input table), to run this check and then add the relevant data to the correct table.

Is this possible to do or do i need to do some batch-processing of the table every so often?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like a post-insert trigger is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer - I think this is what I am looking for. Do you know if the trigger is always active? The data is coming in at real-time so will be continuously be appended (via kafka).